# SD card not working on ubuntu 16.04 but does on Windows

Tags: 16.04, drivers, realtek, sd-card

When I try to edit, create and delete a file on ubuntu I get an Input/Output error. But when I try it on Windows it works. So I think it is a driver problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Formatting also gives Input/Output errors.

When I run `lspci` I think this is my cardreader:

```
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Found a working solution for my Realtek Card reader RTS5209 on a sony vaio SVE15, ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

1) Install the driver found on github at https://github.com/chrisnew/rts_pstor (official Realtek driver won't compile on Ubuntu 16.04), following the instructions contained in the README.md. Maybe you will have to install some additional components (ex. git and/or dkms), cf. detailed instructions linked below.

2) blacklist previous driver (rts_pci)

3) reboot

Detailed instructions at [Realtek Card Reader not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258533/realtek-card-reader-not-working) (first answer). Be careful, there is a typo in the command

```
dkms install rts_pstor/1.11
```

that was

```
dkms install rts_pstor-1.11
```

for me.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Ive already fixed the issue by buying a new drive and reinstalling ubuntu.