# Downloading Smart Card Reader Drivers (18.04LTS)

Tags: 18.04, drivers, dell, smartcard, pcscd

I have a Dell Precision 7540 with a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader. However, I cannot find the drivers anywhere. I have found the Ubtuntu winpack drivers on the Dell site and downloaded them. So I'm asking 2 questions. First, has anyone ever solved this problem before. Second, how do I get the winpack drivers I downloaded(.CAB file) into the additional drivers page.

I would like to add that I downloaded the pcsc installs, but pcsc does not detect anything.

Comment: Information: The RTS5250 is [certified](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/10ec:5260) for use with Ubuntu.

Comment: From and older Ubuntu version, but may help you fix your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/258533/realtek-card-reader-not-working